# SQL connection string with alternate credentials

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, authentication

I have an app written in vb.net (VS 2010) that connects to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database on a domain network. I use Windows Authentication to connect with no problem. I have installed the app on a tablet that uses a "functional" domain account (no permissions to the db). At login, I prompt for the Windows network credentials.  I can pass the userId and password but my login fails. If I also use SSPI along with the userId and password (in the conn string), of course the connection ignores the supplied userId and password.  How do I need to set up SQL to handle a login for both Windows Authentication and allow the userId and password to be supplied?  Or how do I need to write the connection string?

In other words, the user logs into the tablet with an account that cannot be authenticated.  I want to bypass the windows login and have the user supply their windows credentials so I can pass them to SQL to allow access.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need mixed mode authentication set on your sql-server instance: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa905171(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: sql-server instance is already set to mixed mode.  I'm trying to pass the userId and password that is the windows login credentials, not a separate SQL login.  Thanks.

Comment: You need to set the connection string to use a trusted connection see: https://connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: You would have to use impersonation to log on as another user. Question is, how did the user get on the device if they "cannot be authenticated"? And Why would you allow this?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did get this working using impersonation. My client uses functional accounts for certain users to log onto public shared computers/tablets. They do not want the user to log on with their domain credentials to the public computers and in turn have full rights on the public computers/tablets.  So, they created functional accounts for limited use.  However, my application needs to verify they have access to the application and the underlying data.  Thus, the need for logging on to the application with their "real" credentials.